# Where can I find facial fiducial points haarcascade for use with opencv

Tags: opencv, face-detection, face-recognition

I am looking for already trained haarcascades of facial fiducial points (left corner of left eye, right corner of left eye, left corner of right eye, right corner of right eye,  left corner of mouth, right corner of mouth, left, center and right side of nose).
Does anyone know where can I download an already trained haarcascades to use with OpenCV's VJ function?

Comment: I need to get the correct answers first :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I m not so badly mistaken, HaarCascade works with objects not with specific points. There are already classifiers for nose,eye and mouth within opencv data folder. You can detect eyes,nose and mouth with them, than you can find corners of them by using specifically well and wise crafted detection algorithms (use your imagination and mind).

Here an example;

```
CascadeClassifier cascade;  
cascade.load("haarcascade_eye.xml");

Mat im = imread("photo.jpg",0); //0 flag for grayscale

vector<Rect> eyes;
cascade.detectMultiScale(im, eyes, 1.2, 3);

for (int i = 0; i < eyes.size(); i++)
{
    Rect r = eyes[i];
    rectangle(im, Point(r.x, r.y), Point(r.x + r.width, r.y+r.height),CV_RGB(0,255,0));
}

imshow("im",im);
```

This example finds the eyes in the loaded image. Finding mouth and nose is also similar. It finds them as rectangle and we draw these rectangles to image. I don't know if these rectangles are enough for you but if you want more specific points, like center of nose; you will need to do more processing.

Comment: you can train HaarCascades on a corner of an eye (instead of an entire eye for instance) and that should give you the option to detect part of the eye

Answer (score 0):

[In this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15493592/4391129) I found two links to libraries to find facial feature points based on the opencv:

Here are the two libraries:

- first [Flandmarks](http://cmp.felk.cvut.cz/~uricamic/flandmark/)
- second [ASM/AAM](https://code.google.com/p/asmlib-opencv/)