# Facial Feature Points Detection using OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, face-detection

I want to detect the points on a face as shown in the picture

[image]

I am using OpenCV [CascadeClassifier::detectMultiScale](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/objdetect/doc/cascade_classification.html#cascadeclassifier-detectmultiscale).
I am using the haarcascade_frontalface_alt, haarcascade_eye, haarcascade_mcs_mouth xml files.

I am satisfied with the face detection but **not** with the facial feature points detection.

I want the feature points detection to work for the images upto a **distance of 8 feet**.

I am looking for more accuracy and robustness wrt pose(15 degrees) and opening of mouth,  without **compromising speed.**
I am looking for speed of 25fps on an i5 processor.

**Can anyone suggest/refer me any libraries/open source codes for my problem.**

C++ platform.

Comment: can anyone please give me an idea or any other information missing in the question...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try Flandmarks http://cmp.felk.cvut.cz/~uricamic/flandmark/
It extracts 7 feature points but you will not be able to get the feature points for upperlip and the lower lip.

You can try using an ASM mesh to fit the face. There are several implementations that use ASM/AAM.
https://code.google.com/p/asmlib-opencv/ is an open source library which has built in dataset for face images. Do look into it.

Cheers

Comment: @2vision2 which one did u use to achieve result like in question image :)